# how to handle play/pause button of the headphones in react native

Tags: react-native

I just want to handle play/pause button. If the button of the headphones is clicked,I will do somethink. I can control the volume-up or down button but I could not control the play/pause button. Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin called react-native-music-control that handles those things with listeners but there are some limitations when it comes to support both platforms (android + ios).

Check here their documentation is very straight forward. https://github.com/tanguyantoine/react-native-music-control#register-to-events