# Detect headphone buttons react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, headphones

I am trying to detect headphone button clicks in react native.
I want to add listener on play / pause button click from headphone, I have searched many package but can't find good solutions.

Thank you.
I am using

```
"react": "16.6.3",
"react-native": "0.58.5"
```

IOS / Android Platforms.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to handle play/pause button of the headphones in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50456908/how-to-handle-play-pause-button-of-the-headphones-in-react-native)

Comment: No, this not working.

Comment: I'm not saying it's working. This is a duplicate question